# How Compare Times In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, timestamp

I want to compare my variable from may form with the current date :

```
$a = explode('/', $request->expired_at);
$expiredAt = str_replace('/', '-', jalali_to_gregorian($a[0], $a[1], $a[2], ':'));
```

my $expiredAt result -> "2021-03-25" -> insert by user in form

And my short if :

```
return Carbon::now()->toDateString() > $expiredAt ? false : true;
```

but this code returns null result.

Comment: Please show us the value of `$request->expired_at`

Comment: Convert `$expiredAt` to a date then use [carbon to compare the dates](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison) you are currently comparing 2 string representations of dates which is never totally reliable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carbon should be able to parse `expired_at` for you so you parse `expired_at` and see whether `now()` is greater.

```
return ! now()->greaterThan(Carbon::parse($request->expired_at));
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained by @RiggsFolly in the comment, you are comparing 2 strings that is not the best way to compare dates.
You can do it with Carbon comparing function.
In this way:

```
$expiredAt = \Carbon::createFromFormat('YOUR_FORMAT', $request->expired_at);
return Carbon::now()->lte($expiredAt); // You can directly return the value of the comparison
```